# Unable to find template Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.2

After some template renaming mystery happens – twig looking for wrong template and did not find it even it really exists:

```
Unable to find template "form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig" (looked into: /home/travel/www/gai/app/Resources/views, /home/travel/www/gai/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).
```

Symfony debugger points to error at line 31:

```
  30      {% form_theme edit_form 'form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_numbers.html.twig' %}
  31      {{ form_start(edit_form) }}
  32      <div class="box-body">
  33          {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
  34      </div>
```

However as you may notice it fails to find theme `*layout.html.twig` not the `*numbers.html.twig`.

You may say it may be some issue with caching? It may be but I cleared it as well as know how to: `php bin/console cache:clear`, `rm -rf app/cache`. Will be appreciate ideas about what I'm missing. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Here is output of `ls -la app/Resources/views/form/`

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 travel travel 4096 Geg  3 08:56 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 travel travel 4096 Bal 23 23:47 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 travel travel 2399 Geg  3 08:56 bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 travel travel 2577 Geg  3 00:22 bootstrap_3_horizontal_numbers.html.twig
-rw-rw-r--  1 travel travel 9668 Kov 19 10:20 bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
```

Comment: Have you seen `bootstrap_3_horizontal_numbers.html.twig`this file?<br/>Whether there is `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig` inclued or extended in it.

Comment: `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html` do you missing some `.twig` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the output of `ls -la` the most obviously reason should be that your `*layout.html` file is missing the `.twig` ending in the filename.

Error message:

> Unable to find template "form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig"

Filename:

> form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html

Change Filename to:

> form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig

Comment: Thank you. Strangely I don't see it myself. But anyway this does not explains why twig was looking for wrong template.

Comment: Could it be that it tries to load the `_layout` file inside the `_numbers` file? So it bubbles the error up or something similliar. Also do you test it on `/web/app.php` or `/web/app_dev.php`? The first one would require to add `--env=prod` to the clear cache command otherwise it would only clear the development cache. (I just noticed that you also `rm -F` the whole cache dir.. so the question should be irrelevant). Last idea would be something inside the Controller or the config yaml files

Answer (score 0):

You have probably renamed the symfony twig file by accident (if using safe refactoring on phpstorm or something) and now that original file could not be found because it's name is changed. You should locate that file and changed it name back to the original and try again.

Comment: Yes I'm using phpstorm. But the files exists. See my updated question.